# Searching a range by another range

Tags: views

We are developing a Drupal website for displaying properties. Each property has a minimum and maximum size that is available.  The user can search with a minimum and maximum size also.

We need help trying to work out how to setup the View in Drupal 7. For example, a user might search for properties with min size 10,000 sq ft and max size 50,000 sq ft. The following properties would match:

- Property 1 - min size 13,000 sq ft, max size 48,000 sq ft
- Property 2 - min size 10,000 sq ft, max size 50,000 sq ft
- Property 3 - min size 20,000 sq ft, max size 20,000 sq ft
- Property 4 - min size 9,000 sq ft, max size 51,000 sq ft

How should we set this up in the Drupal View? The content type has a min_size and max_size already.

Answer (score 1):

Set up two exposed filters (exposed filters show on the view itself, with the user able to set their own value) one for the min_size field and another for the max_size field.

When setting up the exposed filters you'll have a choice "expose operator." With that choice you can allow the user to choose the operator (e.g. less than, greater than, greater than or equal to, etc.). The end user can use either of the exposed filters or both.

You'll need to be pay attention to your label choices and the help text you create to make sure what you come up with is easy to use and returns the expected results.